# Attic AC Unit Different Electric Line

Tags: wiring, hvac

I had to run a longer power cable for my AC unit that is in my attic. The cable that I bought looks different, and I didn't know if that would be an issue. Both cables are 6/2. The black cable is the new one that I am trying to use. Can I use that one to replace the gray cable?

[image]

Comment: Cable colors mean *almost* nothing. There should be labeling - numbers and codes - printed on the outside of the cables - we need to know what those are.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. Then, get clear, focused pics of the labeling on the housing on both the grey and black cables and [edit] those pics into your question. Odds are good you're OK, but that will help. Also, be aware that the splice between the two _MUST_ be in an approved electrical junction box and that box must be permanently accessible (i.e. not buried behind drywall).

Comment: Thank you, I will add better photos.

Comment: I mean, it's hard to tell from pics, but it certainly looks like the cable with the black sheath is a smaller gauge than the cable with the gray sheath.